# Window Forms Xml Display in Data Grid by using DataSet

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am quite new to Window Forms and Data Sets. I have question looks easy but i cant get around it yet.
I have XML data and i wanted to display it in Window Form  data grid. (it is syncfusion databoundgrid)
My XML Data is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Authors_Table>
  <authors>
    <au_id>172-32-1176</au_id>
    <au_lname>White</au_lname>
    <au_fname>Johnson</au_fname>
    <phone>408 496-7223</phone>
    <addresses>
    <address>10932 Bigge Rd.</address>
    <city>Menlo Park</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zip>94025</zip>
    </addresses>
    <contract>true</contract>
  </authors>
  <authors>
    <au_id>213-46-8915</au_id>
    <au_lname>Green</au_lname>
    <au_fname>Margie</au_fname>
    <phone>415 986-7020</phone>
    <addresses>
    <address>309 63rd St. #411</address>
    <city>Oakland</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zip>94618</zip>
      </addresses>
    <contract>true</contract>
  </authors>
  <authors>
    <au_id>238-95-7766</au_id>
    <au_lname>Carson</au_lname>
    <au_fname>Cheryl</au_fname>
    <phone>415 548-7723</phone>
    <addresses>
    <address>589 Darwin Ln.</address>
    <city>Berkeley</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zip>94705</zip>
      </addresses>
    <contract>true</contract>
  </authors>
  <authors>
    <au_id>267-41-2394</au_id>
    <au_lname>Hunter</au_lname>
    <au_fname>Anne</au_fname>
    <phone>408 286-2428</phone>
    <addresses>
    <address>22 Cleveland Av. #14</address>
    <city>San Jose</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zip>95128</zip>
      </addresses>
    <contract>true</contract>
  </authors>
  <authors>
    <au_id>274-80-9391</au_id>
    <au_lname>Straight</au_lname>
    <au_fname>Dean</au_fname>
    <phone>415 834-2919</phone>
    <addresses>
    <address>5420 College Av.</address>
    <city>Oakland</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zip>94609</zip>
      </addresses>
    <contract>true</contract>
  </authors>
</Authors_Table>
```

"
my code is :

```
string path = "D:/Personal/Project/WinForm/DataSetExaple/DataSetExaple/Test.xml";
            dataSet1.ReadXml(path);
            gridDataBoundGrid1.DataSource = dataSet1;
gridDataBoundGrid1.DataMember = "authors";
```

It shows out put like this
[image: Wrong display.]

But I really want to show like this
[image: Right output]

How to show the child element of the xml node on the same side as sibling in data grid.
Thank you ,
L.E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your xml:

```
  <authors>
    <au_id>172-32-1176</au_id>
    <au_lname>White</au_lname>
    <au_fname>Johnson</au_fname>
    <phone>408 496-7223</phone>
    <addresses>
    <address>10932 Bigge Rd.</address>
    <city>Menlo Park</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zip>94025</zip>
    </addresses>
    <contract>true</contract>
  </authors>
```

Note that you actually have a child element `<addresses> ... </addresses>` intended to link to multiple address groups. Alter your xml to look like the following:

```
  <authors>
    <au_id>172-32-1176</au_id>
    <au_lname>White</au_lname>
    <au_fname>Johnson</au_fname>
    <phone>408 496-7223</phone>
    <address>10932 Bigge Rd.</address>
    <city>Menlo Park</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zip>94025</zip>
    <contract>true</contract>
  </authors>
```

You will get the output you want.

The WinForms `DataGridView` is not designed to render nested records.

Comment: yeh you are right if i change it it will work. But this is just an example data that i have created to test my code. how about without changing xml file but same output?

Comment: Then I repeat ...*The WinForms DataGridView is not designed to render nested records.* ...at least not by default. You may have to look into other controls that do this for you - possibly a DevEx control. If I have answered the question you posted, then you should mark it as the answer. Anything else should be posted as another question. ;)

Comment: you are right on nested records. It doesnt solve my problem but it gives me direction. Thank you